# How to create a thumbnail of video using Aquery

Tags: android, listview, aquery

i am working on listview showing list of video.i am getting url of video from web server.Now i want to create a thumbnail of video using aQuery.i am using this code:

```
     Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("http://"
                + videoList.get(1), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

it is working, but is taking some time while scrolling.

Comment: It's normally, since the video has to be fetched from the url. If you are experiencing app hanging, you are not doing it asynchronously.

Comment: normally means???  i didn't get you.... It is taking some time to create and is not allowing to have a smooth scroll of list view

Comment: It's normally to take some time to generate the thumb. Can you show the code of your `ListAdapter`?

Comment: I solved the problem ,, by creating thumbnail while fetching the data from server.By this way , it wont disturb the scrolling of list view. Anyway Thanks.....